# Unable to autowire MongoTemplate in Springboot

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, spring-boot, maven

I am trying to connect springboot with the remote mongodb which in Linux, I operate it in Win10.
But SpringBoot seems to have trouble wiring up the MongoDB client,exception below.

```
***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************

Description:

Field mongotemplate in com.example.demo.controller.SampleController required a bean of type 'org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate' that could not be found.

The injection point has the following annotations:
    - @org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)


Action:

Consider defining a bean of type 'org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate' in your configuration.
```

Here is my application class/configuration:

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class DemoApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(DemoApplication.class, args);
    }

}
```

The application.properties:
192.168.12.130 is my Linux IP

```
server.port=8080
spring.data.mongodb.uri=mongodb://192.168.12.130:27017/users
```

pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.4.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>demo</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>demo</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>


    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

I discover that when I add this sentence on the Controller that the error is which I mentioned above.

```
@EnableAutoConfiguration(exclude = {MongoAutoConfiguration.class, MongoDataAutoConfiguration.class})
```

If I remove this sentence, the error will be this:

```
com.mongodb.MongoSocketOpenException: Exception opening socket
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.SocketStream.open(SocketStream.java:70) ~[mongodb-driver-core-4.0.5.jar:na]
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.InternalStreamConnection.open(InternalStreamConnection.java:127) ~[mongodb-driver-core-4.0.5.jar:na]
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.DefaultServerMonitor$ServerMonitorRunnable.run(DefaultServerMonitor.java:117) ~[mongodb-driver-core-4.0.5.jar:na]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [na:1.8.0_202]
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
    at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.waitForConnect(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_202]
    at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(DualStackPlainSocketImpl.java:85) ~[na:1.8.0_202]
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:350) ~[na:1.8.0_202]
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:206) ~[na:1.8.0_202]
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:188) ~[na:1.8.0_202]
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:172) ~[na:1.8.0_202]
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392) ~[na:1.8.0_202]
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:589) ~[na:1.8.0_202]
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.SocketStreamHelper.initialize(SocketStreamHelper.java:63) ~[mongodb-driver-core-4.0.5.jar:na]
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.SocketStream.initializeSocket(SocketStream.java:79) ~[mongodb-driver-core-4.0.5.jar:na]
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.SocketStream.open(SocketStream.java:65) ~[mongodb-driver-core-4.0.5.jar:na]
    ... 3 common frames omitted
```

I've tried multiple variations of this, but none of them seem to work. Any ideas?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score -1):

1. have you autowired mongotemplate in your controller like below?

@Autowired

```
private MongoTemplate mongotemplate;
```

2. You can also try creating bean in configuration class like this

@Bean

```
public MongoTemplate MongoTemplate(){
return new MongoTemplate();
}
```

Comment: Very Thanks for your answer!  This is my last term homework and I finished it, but I forgot to come here to reply you ... About this question, my truly problem is I didn't correctly open the mongodb server in my ubuntu. I didn't add the --bind_ip=192.xxx.xx.xx to carry out the order. But ! I really appreciate you to help me that I can contrapuntally find the reason.